# Calling classForCoder in init before super.init

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, xcode6.1-gm-seed

In my iOS app written in Swift I have an Error class, which extends from NSError.

```
class MyError: NSError {

    class var ErrorDomain: String { return "com.domain.app.error" }
    class var ErrorCode: Int { return 0 }

    init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let userInfo: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "data": data
        ]
        super.init(
            domain: self.classForCoder.ErrorDomain,
            code: self.classForCoder.ErrorCode,
            userInfo: userInfo
        )
    }

    [...]

}
```

I have also other error classes that extends from the one above:

```
class MyError2: MyError {

    override class var ErrorDomain: String { return "com.domain.app.error2" }
    override class var ErrorCode: Int { return 0 }

    [...]

}
```

That way I can use init from `MyError` class, and have custom domains and codes for subclassed error objects.

It was working well on Xcode 6.0.1. The problem is, it won't compile in Xcode 6.1. I get this compiler error in `MyError` class in lines:

```
[...]
domain: self.classForCoder.ErrorDomain,
code: self.classForCoder.ErrorCode,
[...]
```

> Use of property 'classForCoder' in base object before super.init initializes it

Is it possible to get `Class` object in `init` before calling `super.init`? I know it could sound strange, but I think my example shows why I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize all instance properties before calling `super.init()`.

But since you are passing values of type properties you could simply write

```
super.init(
        domain: MyError.ErrorDomain,
        code: MyError.ErrorCode,
        userInfo: userInfo
    )
```

Comment: That obviously will work. Unfortunately, when init will be called on `MyError2`, new object will have domain and code from `MyError` instead of `MyError2` class. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Sorry, haven't thought about that.